# Date command in LLNCS documentclass

Tags: date, latex

I'm editing a paper with llncs documentclass. But the `date` command doesn't work. Is there a way to enable it?

```
\date{\today}
```

Comment: Hi! Can you add some additional info? A "minimal working example", starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` would be best

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering!
\documentclass{llncs}
\begin{document}
\title{..}
\author{..}
\institute{..}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
...
...

Comment: @MattAllegro   following the code above, \end{document}

Comment: From latex community I got an answer that you cannot use the date property in llncs class